# Axis-angle representation of angular velocity

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Looking at this paper: [The Vectorial Parameterization of Rotatation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1024265401576). A rotation matrix can be expressed in terms of the axis angle $(\varphi, \mathbf{u})$ as

$$
\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{I} + \sin \varphi\; \mathbf{u}\times  + (1 - \cos \varphi) (\mathbf{u}\times)^2 \quad (\text{Equation (1)})
$$

Combined with
$$
\dot{\mathbf{R}}  = \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \mathbf{R}, \quad (\text{Equation (2)})
$$

it is possible to obtain an axis-angle representaiton of the angular velocity ($\boldsymbol{\omega}$), which is
$$
\boldsymbol{\omega} = \dot{\varphi} \mathbf{u} + \left( \sin \varphi \mathbf{I} + (1 - \cos \varphi) \mathbf{u}\times \right) \dot{\mathbf{u}} \quad (\text{Equation (3)})
$$

Wondering how is (3) obtained from (1) and (2)?

Comment: By today's (hopefully final) edit the formula is shown as stated. Please dive into it and respond.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more accessible article is found in Wikipedia: [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). The cross product $\mathbf{u}\times$ when applied to a vector is the same as multiplication by the skew symmetric matrix
$$
\mathbf{U}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-u_3&u_2\\u_3&0&-u_1\\-u_2&u_1&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
This explains also $\dot{\mathbf{R}}=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{R}$ which is now a matrix multiplication:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{R}}=\boldsymbol{\Omega}\mathbf{R}\quad\text{ where }\quad\boldsymbol{\Omega}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-\omega_3& \omega_2\\\omega_3&0&-\omega_1\\-\omega_2&\omega_1&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Your Equation (1), is more transparently written as
$$\tag{A}
\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{I}+\sin\varphi\,\mathbf{U}+(1-\cos\varphi)\mathbf{U}^2\,.
$$
Flipping the sign of the rotation angle $\varphi$ the inverse rotation matrix is obviously,
$$\tag{B}
\mathbf{R}^{-1}=\mathbf{I}-\sin\varphi\,\mathbf{U}+(1-\cos\varphi)\mathbf{U}^2\,.
$$
Further,
$$\tag{C}
\dot{\mathbf{R}}=\dot\varphi\cos\varphi\,\mathbf{U}+\sin\varphi\,\dot{\mathbf{U}}+\dot\varphi\sin\varphi\,\mathbf{U}^2+(1-\cos\varphi)
(\dot{\mathbf{U}}\mathbf{U}+\mathbf{U}\dot{\mathbf{U}})
\,.
$$
Observe now that
$$
\mathbf{U}^2=\begin{pmatrix}-u_3^2-u_2^2&u_1u_2&u_1u_3\\u_1u_2&-u^2_3-u^2_1&u_2u_3\\u_1u_3&u_2u_3&-u_2^2-u_1^2\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Since the axis of rotation $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)^\top$ has length one this can be written as
$$\tag{D}
\mathbf{U}^2=\begin{pmatrix}u_1^2&u_1u_2&u_1u_3\\u_1u_2&u^2_2&u_2u_3\\u_1u_3&u_2u_3&u_3^2\end{pmatrix}-\mathbf{I}=\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{I}=\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^\top-\mathbf{I}\,.
$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker (tensor) product. Because $\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$ we find from (D) two very simple expressions:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{U}^3&=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^2=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^\top-\mathbf{U}
=\underbrace{(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{u})}_{\mathbf{0}}\mathbf{u}^\top-\mathbf{U}=-\mathbf{U}\tag{E}\\
\mathbf{U}^4&=-\mathbf{U}^2\,.\tag{F}
\end{align}
Further, since $\mathbf{U}$ and $\dot{\mathbf{U}}$ are anti symmetric,
$$\tag{G}
\mathbf{U}\dot{\mathbf{U}}=(\dot{\mathbf{U}}\mathbf{U})^\top\,.
$$
Differentiating $\|\mathbf{u}\|^2=1$ directly yields that $\mathbf{u}$ and $\dot{\mathbf{u}}$ are orthogonal which leads to another useful relation:
$$\tag{H}
\mathbf{U}\dot{\mathbf{U}}\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{0}\,.
$$
To see this just observe that $\dot{u}_1u_1+\dot{u}_2u_2+\dot{u}_3u_3=0$ implies
$$
\mathbf{U}\dot{\mathbf{U}}=\dot{\mathbf{u}}\otimes\mathbf{u}=\dot{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{u}^\top
$$
(very similar to how we got the expression for $\mathbf{U}^2$). Now multiply the matrix $\dot{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{u}^\top$ from the right with
$\mathbf{U}$ and use $\dot{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{u}^\top\mathbf{U}=
\dot{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{U}^\top\mathbf{u})^\top=-\dot{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{U}\mathbf{u})^\top$ (by anti symmetry of $\mathbf{U}$). Then use $\mathbf{U}\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$ which shows (H).

Using the relations (B) to (H) it turns out that
\begin{align}\tag{I}\boxed{\quad
\boldsymbol{\Omega}=\dot{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{R}^{-1}
=\dot{\varphi}\mathbf{U}+\sin\varphi\,\dot{\mathbf{U}}
+(1-\cos\varphi)\Big\{\mathbf{U}\dot{\mathbf{U}}-\dot{\mathbf{U}}\mathbf{U}
\Big\}\,.\quad}
\end{align}
If we note that the term in the curly bracket, when applied to an arbitrary
vector $\mathbf{v}$ corresponds in vector form to
$$
\mathbf{u}\times(\dot{\mathbf{u}}\times\mathbf{v})
-\dot{\mathbf{u}}\times(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v})=
(\mathbf{u}\times\dot{\mathbf{u}})\times\mathbf{v}
$$
(using the [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties)) then
the relation (I) becomes in vector form
\begin{align}\tag{K}\boxed{\quad
\boldsymbol{\omega}
=\dot{\varphi}\mathbf{u}+\sin\varphi\,\dot{\mathbf{u}}
+(1-\cos\varphi)\,\mathbf{u}\times\dot{\mathbf{u}}\,\quad}
\end{align}
which is the Equation (3) that was to prove.

Note also that $\boldsymbol{\Omega}=\dot{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ is an anti symmetric matrix as it must because from
$$
\mathbf{I}=\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}^{-1}=\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}^\top
$$
it follows by differentiation that
$$
\mathbf{0}=\dot{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{R}^\top+\mathbf{R}\dot{\mathbf{R}}^\top
=\dot{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{R}^\top+(\dot{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{R}^\top)^\top
=\dot{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{R}^{-1}+(\dot{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{R}^{-1})^\top\,.
$$
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$